# Total of Totals in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables -

Books -

```
BookNo BookName  BookType
123    ABC          1
555    XYZ          0
```

Shelf

```
Shelf ShelfNo BookNo BookQuantity
  XB   XB01     123    5
  XB   XB02     555    3
  XB   XB03     123    8
```

BooksIssued

```
ShelfNo BookName IssuedDate   QuantityIssued
  XB01    ABC      11/21/2022     2
  XB02    XYZ      11/20/2022     1
  XB03    ABC      11/21/2022     5
```

My goal is to find out total number of books stock we have. The output should be grouped by book. And I have to combine all `shelfNo` which contain the same book and sum their `Shelf.BookQuantity` and then add it to `BooksIssued.QuantityIssued` for that particular book. `Booktype` should be displayed as Children for 0 and 1 for adults.

For example,

Output

```
BookNo BookName BookType Total Stock
123     ABC       adults   20        //(5+8+2+5)
555     XYZ      children   4         //(3+1)
```

So far, I have written this. I know I have chosen extra columns in my query than what I have mentioned in my output format. It is so because I was going step by step to understand the flow.  I wanted to first group the data by book and sum the quantity but it isn't grouping the data by bookno . It is also not summing the `bi.quantityissued`.

```
select s.bookno, b.booktype, s.shelfno, b.bookname, s.bookquantity, 
    sum(bi.quantityissued), bi.issueddate
from Shelf s 
left outer join BooksIssued bi on s.shelfno = bi.shelfno 
left outer join Books b on s.bookno=b.bookno
where s.shelf = 'XB'
    and bi.issueddate between '11/01/2022' and  '11/07/2022'
group by  s.bookno, s.shelfno,  b.booktype,  b.bookname, s.bookquantity, bi.issueddate
```

Please guide me what do I do next. Thank you.

Comment: Schema tip: `BooksIssued` should almost certainly use `BookNo` instead of `BookName`. Also, it seems like you're missing a `BookType` table.

Comment: Also: [the date literals are not correct.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2022/07/13/sql-and-dates/#Formats) Finally, is it possible to have new books issued that do not yet have a shelf entry?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Schema is already created by someone and modifying it is not in my hand. I only have to write a query.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, nope they dont have  a booktype table. and no, is it not possible to have new books issued that do not yet have a shelf entry

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Regarding date, this is how it is displayed in their database

Comment: No, that is a convenience the tooling gives you. The database itself stores the data in a binary, non-human-readable format. The **correct** way to handle those literals is `20221101` and `20221107`. Also, probably better not to use `between` for this, and instead of have two separate statements, where the lower bound is inclusive and the upper bound is _exclusive (`<` instead of `<=`) on the following date (`20221108`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
WITH baseData As
(
    SELECT BookNo, BookQty As Qty
    FROM Shelf s
    WHERE s.shelf = 'XB'
   
    UNION ALL 

    SELECT b0.BookNo, QtyIssued As Qty
    FROM BooksIssued bi
    INNER JOIN Books b0 on b0.BookName = bi.BookName
    WHERE bi.IssuedDate >= '20221101' AND bi.IssuedDate < '20221108' 
), 
grouped As
(
    SELECT BookNo, Sum(Qty) As [Total Stock]
    FROM baseData
    GROUP BY BookNo
)
SELECT b.BookNo, b.BookName, b.BookType, g.[Total Stock]
FROM grouped g
INNER JOIN Books b ON b.BookNo = g.BookNo
```

This also shows one of the reasons (among *several*) the `BooksIssued` table should use `BookNo` instead of `BookName`: it would save you a join.

We can also write this with nested `SELECT` queries instead of the common table expressions (CTEs), but I find the CTE much easier to reason about:

```
SELECT b.BookNo, b.BookName, b.BookType, g.[Total Stock]
FROM (
    SELECT BookNo, Sum(Qty) As [Total Stock]
    FROM (
        SELECT BookNo, BookQty As Qty
        FROM Shelf s
        WHERE s.shelf = 'XB'
       
        UNION ALL 
    
        SELECT b0.BookNo, QtyIssued As Qty
        FROM BooksIssued bi
        INNER JOIN Books b0 on b0.BookName = bi.BookName
        WHERE bi.IssuedDate >= '20221101' AND bi.IssuedDate < '20221108' 
    ) baseData
    GROUP BY BookNo
) g
INNER JOIN Books b ON b.BookNo = g.BookNo
```

This is still missing the `adults` vs `children` book type. You can fix this with a `CASE` expression, or using a [*Table Value Constructor*.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause) I prefer the latter here, because you can add many more types over time in an efficient way and because it sets you up to eventually use a real table, which is what you should have had in the first place:

```
WITH baseData As
(
    SELECT BookNo, BookQty As Qty
    FROM Shelf s
    WHERE s.shelf = 'XB'
   
    UNION ALL 

    SELECT b0.BookNo, QtyIssued As Qty
    FROM BooksIssued bi
    INNER JOIN Books b0 on b0.BookName = bi.BookName
    WHERE bi.IssuedDate >= '20221101' AND bi.IssuedDate < '20221108' 
), 
grouped As
(
    SELECT BookNo, Sum(Qty) As [Total Stock]
    FROM baseData
    GROUP BY BookNo
)
SELECT b.BookNo, b.BookName, bt.Name As BookType, g.[Total Stock]
FROM grouped g
INNER JOIN Books b ON b.BookNo = g.BookNo
INNER JOIN (VALUES (0, 'Childrens'), (1 'Adults') ) AS bt(Type, Name)   
    ON b.BookType = bt.Type;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select bookno BookNo,
        bookname BookName,
        case booktype
            when 1 then 'adults'
            when 0 then 'children'
        end BookType
        SUM(TotalStock) TotalStock
from (

    select b.bookno,
           b.bookname,
           b.booktype,
           sum(bookquantity) TotalStock
    from ..books b
    inner join ..shelf s
        ON b.bookno = s.bookno
    group by b.bookno, b.bookname, b.booktype
    
    UNION ALL
    
    select b.bookno,
           b.bookname,
           b.booktype,
           sum(QuantityIssued) TotalStock
    from ..books b
    inner join ..shelf s
        ON b.bookno = s.bookno
    inner join ..booksissued bi
        ON s.shelfno = bi.shelfno
            and b.bookname = bi.bookname
    group by b.bookno, b.bookname, b.booktype
) s
group by bookno, bookname, booktype
```

Comment: What's with the `nolock`? Whoever told you it was an easy "go faster" trick was **wrong**. It can make a difference, but it's much less impact than you've been led to believe and anywhere it actually does help is because it's highly likely there is stale data involved.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Sorry, force of habit . . . the database admins at my office are strict enforcers of it . . . I've deleted